# Бот получит доступ к Вашему ip-адресу и основной информации об устройстве. Почему у меня появляется это сообщение а на другом боте его нет?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Сделал я web apps в ТГ.
Вывожу ссылку в телеграмм боте на своё приложение
И получаю такое окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот так выводится ссылка.

```csarp
                InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboard = new(new[]
                {
                    InlineKeyboardButton.WithWebApp("Test",new(){Url =$"https://mysite.com/login?userid={message.Chat.Id}" })
                    
                });

                Message sentMessage = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                 chatId: chatId,
                 text: "Test",
                 replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard,
                 cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Но есть приложения при открытии которых нет такой плашки. 
Я не буду давать ссылку на ТГ бота в котором нет такой плашки, там шиткоины.
Что я не так делаю?
 Мб траст и если много людей пользуется приложением то плашка пропадает?